# Why does this small padding value result in such a large amount of space?

Tags: html, css

Consider this basic HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

and CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding-top: 0rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

([Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/bdesham/3bxn1q2q/))

When the `padding-top` is set to `0rem` (or if that line is omitted), there is very little gray background above the text. But if I set `padding-top: 0.1rem` then all of a sudden there is a huge amount of gray background above the text—about as much as there is to the left of the text. I would expect to see only one tenth as much padding on the top as on the left. Why the seemingly odd behavior?

Comment: It's the margin of the p, not the padding

Comment: @HaukurHaf - No, rem is a unit. CSS3 I believe. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#lengths

Comment: using inspect element in chrome when u click on div>p u see that ur p tag have 16px margin top,u can add `div p {margin-top:0px;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is due to "[margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)". According to the MDN:

> If there is no border, **padding**, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up **outside the parent**.

Your `<p>` tag has top and bottom margins by default.
The margins will collapse and will appear outside of the `<div>`.
But if you add top-padding to the `<div>`, then the `<p>` margins no longer collapse and appear inside the `<div>`.

You can get rid of the `<p>` margins like so:

```
p {
  margin:0;
}
```